# Yum not updating on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

Tags: redhat

I am currently trying to update my server. I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago).

If I enter any command such as **yum update yum**, I receive the following error:

```
[root@u15457812000001 ~]# yum update yum

Loaded plugins: rhui-lb

Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://rhua-rcd-01.vic.svc.cloud.telstra.com/pulp/mirror//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/6/6Server/x86_64/optional/os error was

14: Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-optional-rpms. Please verify its path and try again
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: check your proxy settings and then repository for the update process.

Comment: @Sachith I am new to this. Can you please advise how I do this please?

Comment: did you create an account and register for packages?